Sizing a Peltier plate module
I am working on designing a small medical cabinet That needs to be cooled. The cabinet volume is about .05 cubic meters. The inside needs to be cooled to about 38 degrees F. Does anyone know how to correctly size the Peltier plate? What wattage plate do I use?

The problem with Peltier elements is that they can only generate a certain temperature differential between cold and hot side, not an absolute temperature. 8 Fahrenheit = ~3.3°C which is pretty cold so it may not be possible at all in a warm environment.

I need to cool to 38F not 8F.

Ack, my bad. But 38 F is still 3.3 C (sorry, I'm from metric land).

3-4 degrees C  is a standard refrigeration temp. I am in Australia, thanks for the help

So, say I am in a 25 C environment can it get down to 3-4 C, What wattage size system do I need to cool a space of .05 cubic meters? Thanks

This is a system issue that depends on the heat loss through the insulation, through the Peltier itself (can be quite substantial) and the heat created by the Peltier device itself (again, quite substantial). From the application, I assume the item being kept at a low temperature is not actually producing heat, but if it was you'd have to include that. If you have to have a two-stage TEC the second stage is mostly moving heat created by the smaller stage- it's like a rocket, the payload gets smaller and smaller as a percentage of the rocket size.
You'll need to get rid of a lot of heat from the hot side, which typically means a heat sink and a fan. If you get the heat sink from an old school supplier it will come with data such as thermal resistance vs. air flow and you can estimate air flow from a fan specs and verify with a handheld anemometer. TECs are very inefficient. If you compare with a TE car cooler it's maybe going to be marginal even at 25°C maximum ambient.
Anyway, you can measure (or model) the heat loss of your insulated enclosure and apply detailed design parameters from a supplier such as Laird (the current owner of familiar legacy producer Melcor). No-name TEC modules are not going to come with that kind of data and support.


Thank you very much.
